# How many genes per 23 chromosomes in human genome?

Tags: human-genetics, chromosome, human-genome

It is estimated that humans have between 20,000 and 25,000 genes. Every person has two copies of each gene, one inherited from each parent.

There are 46 chromosomes, half from the mother, half from the father.

Does this mean that there are

a) approximately 20-25,000 genes on the 23 chromosomes inherited from the mother, and 20-25,000 genes on the 23 chromosomes inherited from the father, or

b) approximately 10-12,500 genes on the 23 chromosomes inherited from the mother, and 10-12,5000 genes on the 23 chromosomes inherited from the father?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details. Thanks!

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: I don't have the ability to do that, but you can Flag your post for moderator intervention and ask for this to be deleted (may not be possible with an answer) or closed. ——— Please also note that "homework" on this site includes "self learning", please follow the link in my first comment for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer A is correct!

The human genome has around 20,000 genes. In both, diploid and haploid chromosome-count, the gene-count stays the same; grown humans have 2 alleles per gene in most of their cells, which is considered 'diploid'. [Gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete) are haploid.

*Willyard, C., Expanded human gene tally reignites debate. Nature, 2018. 558(7710): p. 354-355.*

Comment: Please don't encourage posting of "homework" questions which do not show research efforts.

Comment: I did spend quite a lot of time searching for a clear answer to this question. I couldn't find one and that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: The aim of stack exchange is to develop an extended topic-related FAQ. I did not find this question here. As this is a natural question that I remember from my own study-years, I really don't care if this is homework; as long as it serves a purpose on the site / for google, it should always be accepted.

Comment: This isn't 'homework' by the way. I'm studying on my own, for myself. PS @KaPy3141 : thank you.